# How to remove Zoom "Talking:" pop up on second screen

Tags: zoom-meeting

I'm using Zoom Desktop Client on macOS with a two screen setup, using one for Zoom and the other for working on other stuff; however, at the top of the latter I keep having this pop up window:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update Zoom and it should go away.

If it is still appearing, you can try clicking on "View Options", which appears next to the green bar "You are viewing ____'s screen" and choose Side-by-side mode

Ref: https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/jguurz/help_how_to_remove_zoom_talking_pop_up_on_second/gbu2jxb?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3